How to create two structs that are identical but of different types in Rust?
I am learning Rust. As I am a physicist, I am starting with a simple particles simulator, which is something I have previously done in C++. I wrote the following simple code:
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PhysicalVector {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

impl PhysicalVector {
    fn add(&mut self, other: &PhysicalVector) {
        self.x = self.x + other.x;
        self.y = self.y + other.y;
        self.z = self.z + other.z;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Particle {
    position: PhysicalVector,
    velocity: PhysicalVector,
}

fn main() {
    let mut particle = Particle {
        position: PhysicalVector {x: 0., y: 0., z: 0.},
        velocity: PhysicalVector {x: 0., y: 0., z: 1.},
    };
    
    dbg!(&particle);
    
    particle.position.add(&PhysicalVector{x: 1., y: 0., z: 0.}); // This is ok!
    particle.position.add(&particle.velocity); // This is a mistake, you cannot add velocity and position!!
    
    dbg!(&particle);
}

which works, but is prone to physics mistakes as it uses the same data type for position and for velocity, thus enabling to do things such as particle.position.add(&particle.velocity) which is clearly something that should not compile under the laws of physics, and would it be nice to make it not compile in Rust as well.
One "brute force" solution is to replicate the definition of each different kind of vector, like this:
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Position {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

impl Position {
    fn add(&mut self, other: &Position) {
        self.x = self.x + other.x;
        self.y = self.y + other.y;
        self.z = self.z + other.z;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Velocity {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

impl Velocity {
    fn add(&mut self, other: &Velocity) {
        self.x = self.x + other.x;
        self.y = self.y + other.y;
        self.z = self.z + other.z;
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Particle {
    position: Position,
    velocity: Velocity,
}

fn main() {
    let mut particle = Particle {
        position: Position {x: 0., y: 0., z: 0.},
        velocity: Velocity {x: 0., y: 0., z: 1.},
    };
    
    dbg!(&particle);
    
    particle.position.add(&Position{x: 1., y: 0., z: 0.}); // This is ok!
    particle.position.add(&particle.velocity); // Now this does not compile, ok!
    
    dbg!(&particle);
}

However, this is obviously not the way to go. What is the correct way of doing this in Rust? I mean, creating two data types Position and Velocity that are identical in all except in the data type?

You typically solve this problem in Rust using so-called "newtypes" which are structs that contain a single value.  Often this is used to implement traits that your crate doesn't define on types your crate doesn't define, but it can also be used to create semantic differences between types where the underlying data is identical -- exactly what is going on here.
Start with the vector (the underlying data type):
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PhysicalVector {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
}

Then create the newtypes:
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Position(pub PhysicalVector);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Velocity(pub PhysicalVector);

Now you can implement add for each type separately, which will prevent adding together two differently-typed values.
If you want to provide access to the underlying values directly through Position and Velocity values then you can implement Deref and DerefMut on them. (This will allow you to use e.g. some_position.x instead of some_position.0.x.)
impl Deref for Position {
    type Target = PhysicalVector;

    fn deref(&self) -> &PhysicalVector {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Position {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut PhysicalVector {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

// Repeat for Velocity

If you have many such types, it may be useful to create a macro that defines the struct as well as implements Deref* on them.  You can then put all common functionality in the macro, and add type-specific functionality separately.

A second approach would be to use generic types as a tag.  For example:
#[derive(Debug)]
struct PhysicalVector<T> {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64,
    _t: PhantomData<T>,
}

struct Position;
struct Velocity;

Now you can have PhysicalVector<Position> and PhysicalVector<Velocity>.  The advantage of this approach is that you can implement add generically one time and still restrict to only add matching types:
impl<T> PhysicalVector<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, other: &Self) {
        self.x = self.x + other.x;
        self.y = self.y + other.y;
        self.z = self.z + other.z;
    }
}

Note that the Self type must exactly match, so if you are calling add on a PhysicalVector<Position>, then other cannot be a reference to PhysicalVector<Velocity>.  This satisfies the constraint that the types have the same structure but are distinct types that cannot be substituted for each other.
The drawback to this approach is the required PhantomData member, which makes literal values cumbersome to specify.  (A new factory function can help here.)
This approach also is a bit more "dirty" in that the tag type is injected into the type containing the base representation, even though that type isn't actually "needed" in the definition (which the required PhantomData member highlights).

I guess the macro part will allow me to avoid code duplication for methods like e.g. add? If you can add an example of how to do this with the macros that would be nice, as I still did not reach the section about macros in the Rust book. Will go through it now anyhow, but having the example here will help for sure.

@user171780 Note the edit I made -- generics can also work here, though with a few drawbacks.

Ok, thanks, I will go through it. I started today with Rust so will take me a while to digest.

In the approach with generics (which look a lot like templates in C++?), how do you create an instance of such a thing? let pos = PhysicalVector<Position> {x=0., y=0., z=0.}; is giving me errors about lifetime.

While you can implement Deref[Mut] that is an anti pattern and discouraged by the API guidlines

@cafce25 ... Ok. Nevermind that the standard library provides different advice.

@cafce25 Heck, the standard library implements Deref on Cow and ManuallyDrop, the latter being decidedly not a smart pointer, and the former arguably being a smart pointer but only in the borrowed case.

"a value of the type transparently behaves like a value of the target type;" But you create the newtype precicely so it doesn't behave the same way.

@cafce25 No, in this instance the newtype is created to allow separate implementations on top of the newtype, but the behavior with respect to the underlying type is transparent -- the same way an Arc<T> is not a T (it has extra stuff) but can also transparently act like a T. And no, ManuallyDrop cannot possibly be considered a smart pointer, unless we consider all wrappers (including those in my answer) as smart pointers. ManuallyDrop owns its value inline and provides direct access to it; that's not a pointer in any meaningful sense of the word, just like any other newtype.

Separate implementations that behave the same? Otherwise it's to support different behavior.

Those two objectives are not in conflict. You can implement functionality exclusive to a newtype on top of it while still allowing transparent access to the underlying value. So Position can have its own capabilities, but still transparently behave like a PhysicalVector.

I mean ignoring the standard library recommendations and the API guidelines is your pergoative... It's still a bad practice to do so.

I'm following the standard library recommendations quite literally to the letter. The API guidelines are in conflict with them (or, more precisely, they impose a more narrow restriction that is within the bounds of the standard library documentation, but this is not true of the converse).

Moreover "These guidelines should not in any way be considered a mandate that crate authors must follow".
